# Android How to increase clickable area?

Tags: java, android

I want to increase the touch are a button or tab.
Here it a picture of an example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7pep.png)

Thank you!!

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424933/6482813) Using TouchDelegate API.

Answer (score 0):

You could archive this by using [TouchDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html)

As the documentation said:

> Helper class to handle situations where you want a view to have a
>   larger touch area than its actual view bounds. The view whose touch
>   area is changed is called the delegate view. This class should be used
>   by an ancestor of the delegate. To use a TouchDelegate, first create
>   an instance that specifies the bounds that should be mapped to the
>   delegate and the delegate view itself.

Lars Vogel provided an excellent example at his [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/04/15/android-using-touchdelegates/)